# Is it considered overfit a decision tree with a perfect attribute?

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, classification, decision-tree, supervised-learning

I have a 6-dimensional training dataset where there is a perfect numeric attribute which separates all the training examples this way: if TIME<200 then the example belongs to class1, if TIME>=200 then example belongs to class2. J48 creates a tree with only 1 level and this attribute as the only node.

However, the test dataset does not follow this hypothesis and all the examples are missclassified. I'm having trouble figuring out whether this case is considered overfitting or not. I would say it is not as the dataset is that simple, but as far as I understood the definition of overfit, it implies a high fitting to the training data, and this I what I have. Any help?

Comment: Are there other classes besides class1 and class2?

Comment: No, just the two classes.

Comment: Then why do you need more information to classify the examples? In other words, the training data is flawed because you *don't* need any more information to classify the examples.

Answer (score 1):

> However, the test dataset does not follow this hypothesis and all the examples are missclassified. I'm having trouble figuring out whether this case is considered overfitting or not. I would say it is not as the dataset is that simple, but as far as I understood the definition of overfit, it implies a high fitting to the training data, and this I what I have. Any help?

Usually great training score and bad testing means overfitting. But this assumes IID of the data, and you are clearly violating this assumption - your training data is completely different from the testing one (there is a clear rule for the training data which has no meaning for testing one). In other words - your train/test split is incorrect, or your whole problem does not follow basic assumptions of where to use statistical ml. Of course we often fit models without valid assumptions about the data, in your case - the most natural approach is to drop a feature which violates the assumption the most - the one used to construct the node. This kind of "expert decisions" should be done prior to building any classifier, you have to think about "what is different in test scenario as compared to training one" and remove things that show this difference - otherwise you have heavy skew in your data collection, thus statistical methods will fail.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is an overfit. The first rule in creating a training set is to make it look as much like any other set as possible.  Your training set is clearly different than any other. It has the answer embedded within it while your test set doesn't. Any learning algorithm will likely find the correlation to the answer and use it and, just like the J48 algorithm, will regard the other variables as noise. The software equivalent of Clever Hans.

You can overcome this by either removing the variable or by training on a set drawn randomly from the entire available set. However, since you know that there is a subset with an embedded major hint, you should remove the hint.

You're lucky. At times these hints can be quite subtle which you won't discover until you start applying the model to future data.